# How to solve this Goursat Problem? (PDE) Inhomogeneous

Tags: partial-differential-equations, wave-equation

Solve the following Goursat problem for $u(x,t)$: $$u_{tt} = u_{xx} + 4cos(2t)$$ $(t >0,−t <x <t)$

$$u(t,t) = t^2, \ \ \ \ \ \ \  u(−t,t) = \text{arctan} \ t $$

My thoughts are as follows convert in the form of $$u_{\zeta \eta}$$ and then we can solve. I have an example which I was just following which is attached but I'm not too sure how to go about solving with the extra $ 4cos(2t)$.

> [image: Solution to a question given at the top of the picture]

I've attempted to do the same but not too sure how to continue / know if this is the right method. $$u_{\zeta \eta} + 4cos(2(\eta - \zeta)) = 0 $$

If this is correct how do we go to $u(x,t)$ from this? (Perhaps, integrate w.r.t $\eta$ followed by $\zeta$ ?

I was hoping someone could help me with this, it would be really appreciated (and if you do, could you try explain this method - I want to learn this method please)

Thank you!

\hline

Edit: If someone could explain the boundary conditions also that would be helpful because it isn't in the regular form of $$u(x,0)= \phi_1(x)$$ - it's really different, which I'm a bit confused about :/

$\textbf{EDIT 2}:$ I've just attempted to do the following to change the variables from $u \rightarrow v$.
Define $$u = u_p + v$$, where $u_p = -cos(2t)$ this yields $$v_{tt} = v_{xx}$$. THen using method from above get $$v_{\zeta \eta} = 0$$. Now, I'm confused again.

Comment: I'm not sure why you didn't just follow your own advice to integrate with respect top $\xi$ and $\eta$? You made the coordinate transform into $(x,t) \to (\xi(x,t),\eta(x,t))$ and found the PDE then becomes $u_{\xi \eta} = 4 \cos(2(\xi-\eta))$. Now you just solve the equation. Integrate with respect to $\xi$ first $$u_{\eta} = 2 \sin(2(\xi-\eta)) + f(\eta)$$ then integrate with respect to $\eta$ $$u = -\cos(2(\xi-\eta)) + F(\eta) + G(\xi)$$ where $F = \int f$. Now apply the initial conditions. This gives the same result as letting $u = u_{p} + v$ as $v = F(\eta) + G(\xi)$.

Comment: Wow, I was just confused on how to do the integration but thank you very much. If you would like to write as an answer I can click the tick for it. This helps very much thank you! @mattos

Comment: Might I suggest that _you_ answer your own question below and accept it. I always feel it is better that the OP answers their own question as that way they can demonstrate their understanding and (hopefully) get positive feedback from others, including upvotes etc. Plus you get a badge for answering your own question I think. Perhaps solve it both ways, first using the coordinate transformation directly on the whole problem and secondly by letting $u = v + u_{p}$.